# Rails authentication gift list for each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, model, relationship

I am trying to get to grips with the basics of authentication in Rails. To start with I have used the nifty_authentication generator by Ryan Bates. It's helping me learn the basic options for user logins etc.

I have a simple application the has a person and gift table in the database. The idea is, each user creates a list of people and then assigned possible gifts to each of those people.

So from a structural point of view:

```
person belongs to user
gift belongs to person
```

So I have the models set up as follows.

**person model**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :gifts
end
```

**gift model**

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :person
end
```

**user model**

```
currently doesn't contain any belongs_to has_many etc.
```

How do I go about making sure each user has their own list of people. So one user cannot see another users list of people or gifts.

Would I simply add the following to the user model?

```
has_many :people
```

and the following to the person model?

```
belongs_to :user
```

Would that work, or am I missing something?

Thanks,

Danny

**UPDATE:** 
The app so far is on Heroku and Github.

http://giftapp.heroku.com/

http://github.com/dannyweb/GiftApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would that work, or am I missing
>   something?

Very short answer: yes that would work; no you are not missing something.

---

I looked at your code.

Instead of:

```
def index
  @people = Person.find(:all)
end
```

You need something along the lines of:

```
def index
  @people = current_user.people
end
```

Where `current_user` is the `User` object that refers to the logged in user.

In the `create` method you will need to assign the newly created person to the current_user:

```
def create
  @person = Person.new(params[:person])
  @person.user = current_user # This associates @person with current_user
  if @person.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created person."
    redirect_to @person
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I have done the changes I suggested and added a column in the people table called user_id. Everything works, however, everyone can see all people. It's still one big communal list.

Comment: When displaying the list of people you will need something like `current_user.people` instead of `Person.all`. I don't know the nifty_authentication generator, but it should supply an object for logged in user.

Comment: In the views or the people controller?

Comment: Ok, I changed it to `@people = current_user.people`. The app still works and I can create new people but they are not showing up when after I leave the show person page. Once I click to go back to the homepage there are no people listed. Do I also need to make changes to the show view?

Comment: That's because you don't assign the new people to the current_user... hold on, I will show you how to do that.

Comment: This means that `current_user` is `nil`. I am having a look at nifty_authentication now...

Comment: Looks like you have to include the include the Authentication module in your Application controller.

Comment: Strange.. looking at your code on Github and it looks fine. Maybe your session expired. Can you login again and try again?

Comment: I have just stopped the localhost, dropped the db and then re-migrated and started the localhost again. Same problem. It's really weird.

Comment: OK, I figured it out. You have to add `before_filter :login_required` at the top of your PeopleController. On the second line after `class PeopleController < ApplicationController`.

Comment: This before filter prevents you from going to a page if you are not logged in. You have to add it on controller you don't want people to access without logging in.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that there is still a security risk in the edit method. You can enter the id of a person in the URL that doesn't belong to you. So you'd better replace `User.find(params[:id])` with `current_user.find(params[:id])`. Same goes for the `destroy` method. Good luck.